# Keyboard Events in r.interactor

Tags: webgl, xtk

i think i'm getting familiar with this library.

**1)**
i want to do a volume rendering like in [lesson 10](http://lessons.goxtk.com/10/)

i want to check whether the user pressed "v" and run a function

this is what i have tried:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var r = new X.renderer3D();
    r.init();

    var volume = new X.volume();
    volume.file = 'http://lessons.goXTK.com/data/avf.nrrd';
    var vr = false;

    function vRender() {
        if (vr) {
            volume.volumeRendering = true;
            volume.opacity = 0.15;
            r.render();
        }
    }


    r.interactor.onKey = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 86) {
            vr = true;
            vRender();
        }
    }

    r.add(volume);
    r.camera.position = [120, 80, 160];
    r.render();

};
```

**2)** how can i grab one of the slice-layers or disable two of the three axis?
does it work in a similar way like what i've tried?

```
var volume = new X.volume();
volume.file = 'http://lessons.goXTK.com/data/avf.nrrd';

volume.sliceX.visible = false;
volume.sliceZ.visible = false;
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2)

Yes, it is possible in a similiar way. Check out the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/haehn/qxMtk/

The difference is that `volume._sliceX` is not available (not exported during compilation) so you have to go through the children. Each `X.volume` has 3 children 0,1,2 which are the X,Y,Z slices.

Also, the volume has to be created (which happens during parsing initiated by `r.render()`) before you can access the children so we have to do the stuff in `onShowtime` or after.

Answer (score 1):

1) I just tried your code and it almost works perfectly. (Unfortunately onKey events don't work in JSFiddle so I can't post a fiddle).

I just added the `volume.modified()` line to fire a `X.event.ModifiedEvent` and make sure the switch between slicing and volume rendering happens properly.

```
  function vRender() {

    if (vr) {

      volume.volumeRendering = true;
      volume.opacity = 0.15;
      **volume.modified();**
      r.render();
    }
  }


  r.interactor.onKey = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 86) {
      vr = true;
      vRender();
    }
  };
```